# Maven truncating full path of global settings in output

Tags: java, windows, maven

I installed Maven with Choco: `choco install maven`

Looking for my global settings:

```
> mvn -X
...
Reading global settings from C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
...
```

How do I get the full path? When I list the dir (before it's truncated) I see no child folders there:

```
> ls C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\


    Directory: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM            228 m2.conf
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM           5741 mvn
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM           6349 mvn.cmd
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM           1485 mvnDebug
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM           1668 mvnDebug.cmd
------          8/27/19   5:01 PM           1532 mvnyjp
```

Comment: It's not truncated - `..` means "parent" - so the path should be `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\conf\settings.xml`

Comment: I guess i misunderstood the output. So its the path of the mvn binary followed immediately but the relative path of the global settings file? Is that always how it is displayed?

Comment: The question is: Why do you need the path of the `settings.xml` file?

Comment: because i need to edit my global setting.xml?

Comment: @red888 it's `Reading global settings from C:\Java\maven\bin\..\conf\settings.xml` on my machine, so it looks like the default configuration does use the relative path.

Comment: _Never_ edit your global settings file. Instead, put a `settings.xml` into the `.m2` directory in your home directory.